# Проблема с путями в python

Tags: python, path

Стркутура моего проекта следующая

```
.
├── ./app
│   ├── ./app/config.py
│   ├── ./app/coub.service
│   ├── ./app/drivers
│   │   └── ./app/drivers/chromedriver
│   ├── ./app/headers
│   │   └── ./app/headers/user-agent.txt
│   ├── ./app/main.py
```

В файле config.py находится несколько строк с переменными для useragent и chromedriver

```
# Пользовательский агент
PATH_HEADERS = Path(Path.cwd(), 'headers', 'user-agent.txt')
USERAGENT = choice(open(f'{PATH_HEADERS}').read().split("\n")) if os.path.isfile(f'{PATH_HEADERS}') else 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
# cromedriver
PATH_DRIVERS = Path(Path.cwd(), 'drivers', 'chromedriver')
DRIVERS = PATH_DRIVERS if os.path.isfile(f'{PATH_DRIVERS}') else os.path.abspath('/media/hdd/Project/Coub-Assistant-Telegram-bot/app/drivers/chromedriver')
```

При запуске проекта из директории проекта, проект запускается и работает

```
(env) nonadminus@debian:/media/hdd/Project/Coub-Assistant-Telegram-bot/app$ python3.6 main.py 
Connection pool of Request object is smaller than optimal value (8)
******************************
```

Но как только я начинаю использовать сервис systemd командой

```
service coub start
```

У меня возникает ошибка

```
Jun 22 10:34:28 debian python3.6[13062]:   (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
Jun 22 10:34:28 debian python3.6[13062]:   (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
```

Содержимое coub.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Instance to Coub Assistant Telegram bot
After=network.target

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/media/hdd/Project/Coub-Assistant-Telegram-bot/app
Environment="PATH=/media/hdd/Project/Coub-Assistant-Telegram-bot/env/bin"
ExecStart=/media/hdd/Project/Coub-Assistant-Telegram-bot/env/bin/python3.6 main.py
Type=simple
User=root

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Я предполагаю что это происходит из-за неправильных путей в config.py

Помогите разобраться пожалуйста. Хочется чтобы мой бот работал независимо от того где он будет запущен

Comment: как вариант узнавать директорию файла и после этого уже ее распростронять по нужным путям до файла `os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` как пример. Path.cwd() отображает путь нынешней директории, скорее всего когда вы вызываете у вас по дефолту запускается с корневой директории

Comment: BASE_DIR + ваш путь от корня проекта. Попробуйте использовать этот путь.

Comment: Кст, `open` умеет работать с `Path`, поэтому `open(f'{PATH_HEADERS}')` -> `open(PATH_HEADERS)`. Кст, сам `Path` умеет работать как `open`, поэтому `open(f'{PATH_HEADERS}').read().split("\n")` -> `PATH_HEADERS.read_text().split("\n")` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.html#pathlib.Path.read_text). И для получения строк лучше не `split('\n')` использовать а `splitlines()` (https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines). Вообще, `Path` имеет аналоги для функций из `os.path.` поэтому лучше через методы `Path` работать :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Path.cwd()
```

Возвращает путь откуда был запущен интерпретатор. Когда ты запускаешь скрипт как сервис, то путь уже не тот который ты ожидаешь. Пэтому BASE_DIR тебе нужно получить из переменной `__file__` которая будет содержать полный путь до текущего файла.

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent

# Пользовательский агент
PATH_HEADERS = BASE_DIR / 'headers' / 'user-agent.txt'
USERAGENT = choice(PATH_HEADERS.read_text().split("\n")) if PATH_HEADERS.is_file() else 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Trident/7.0; rv:11.0) like Gecko'
# cromedriver
PATH_DRIVERS = BASE_DIR / 'drivers' / 'chromedriver'
DRIVERS = PATH_DRIVERS if PATH_DRIVERS.is_file() else os.path.abspath('/media/hdd/Project/Coub-Assistant-Telegram-bot/app/drivers/chromedriver')
```

UPD. хром не хочет запускаться из под рута в целях безопасности. Для игнорирования этого требуется добавить опцию запуска `--no-sandbox`.

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)
```

Comment: Похоже я разобрался почему мой бот не запускается. Первым делом я запустил его от обычного пользователя, проблемы обнаружено не было. Запуск бота от пользователя root даёт сбой как в тексте моего вопроса. Если решу этот вопрос, то напишу что сделал в ответе

Comment: обновил ответ. теперь все будет работать

Comment: Спасибо огромнейшее! А то я уже голову сломал чего боту не хватает)